# What's the difference between exchange spin wave and magnetostatic spin wave?

Tags: waves, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

So far I've heard of three kinds of spin waves

- Magnetostatic spin waves (MSW)
- Dipole-exchange spin waves (DESW)
- Exchange spin waves (ESW)

What's the difference?